# flex - don't let the drag icon get out of the drop target

Tags: apache-flex, drag, itemrenderer, droptarget

I have a list with itemrenderer with dragEnabled true and dropEnabled true. Now, I am trying to tell flex not to let the dragged item (even the icon indication) leave the drop panel. I don;t care if it stop the dragging or just freezes it as if it was the application border - and I cannot. I tried to stop the dragging on dragExit handler but it seems to ignore it. Does anyone know of a working mechanism to do such? (Flex 4)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try on drag exit :

- a setfocus on a stage element other than the item on dragExit
- or a mouseEnabled false on the items

Alternatively you could try listen to mouseOut event and try to the same.

Comment: The mouseEnabled or setFocus tip didn't make it. Why would mouseOut work?

Comment: the mouseOut might capture better the fact that the mouse is leaving the list rather than the item with dragExit. It might be more reliable.

Comment: The DragExit does catch the event, but I don't find anything I can tell him to stop the drag or event stop the move (stopDrag doesn't do anything...)